# Buscar ID que contengan una palabra

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando seleccionar `inputs` que contengan cierta palabra en el `id`
Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma, pero los id, aparte de contener una palabra, contienen el simbolo `]`, por lo que al buscar con jquery, da el siguiente error

```js
   function prueba() {
    var value = "UNIT_PRICE" + "]";
    var prueba = $("[id*="+value+"]").val();
    console.log(prueba);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="Price[546][UNIT_PRICE]" type="text">

<button onclick="prueba()">Buscar</button>
```

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [id*=UNIT_PRICE]]

Comment: Y por qué no quitas los corchetes de la id directamente? Y si tienes varios con el mismo valor, podrías usar data-price, ya que el id debería de ser único.

Comment: Es un desarrollo enorme, es inviable quitarlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no puedes eliminar los corchetes, la solución sería algo así:

```js
   function prueba() {
    //var value = "UNIT_PRICE"; // No añadas un corchete al final de UNIT_PRICE
    //Si de verdad necesitas añadir los corchetes, tienes que hacerlo así:
    var value = "\\[UNIT_PRICE\\]";
    var prueba = $("input[id*=" + value + "]").val();
    console.log(prueba);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="Price[546][UNIT_PRICE]" type="text">

<button onclick="prueba()">Buscar</button>
```

Comment: He editado para mostrarte cómo quedaría si necesitas buscar con los corchetes, cualquiera de las dos maneras funciona en tu ejemplo así que yo optaría por la versión sin corchetes